# Crop one shapefile using another shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, splitting

In QGIS 2.0.1, is there a way to automatically slice up one shapefile and export it as multiple files using polygons defined in another shapefile?

I have a detailed shapefile that categorizes the land ownership of the entire state of Arizona.  (It's called "az_surf_mgmt" on [this page](http://www.blm.gov/az/st/en/prog/maps/gis_files.html).)  As a whole, it far exceeds the size and complexity restrictions of [KML support in Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport?csw=1).  So I want to take that file and chop it into individual counties, or perhaps game management units, as defined by another shapefile obtained elsewhere.

I found an [almost identical question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37226/how-to-crop-shapefiles-in-qgis), but the accepted answer does not address how this might be done automatically.  If the answer requires that I learn Python and PyQGIS, so be it.

Comment: I'm not sure if QGIS terminology is the same, but ArcGIS calls this operation a [Split](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000006000000).

Comment: is this not a use for Spatial Query. Whereby you want to query what polygons fall within another polygon.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS does have a split function but it splits a shapefile into subsidiaries by attribute not geometry.  However, you can still use this in a very simple process. Ensure your counties (or game units) data has a unique id field distinct from your other data. Intersect your shapefile with your counties and then use `Vector->Data Management Tools->Split Vector Layer`.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I use 2.14.5.LTR (german gui).

This sound like a two-step analysis for me. First you should do a `Join attributes by location` (search in the `processing toolbox`). In your example this would join the county attribute to each feature of your `az_surf_mgmt` layer. Then with the attributes merged to this layer, you can split it by attribute using the `split vector layer` tool. For convenience, you might put these together with the graphical modeler.

Join attributes by location:

[image]

Split vector layer:

[image]