# QGIS: Delete information from rasters and shapes that are out of country borders

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, clip

I am trying to make topographic maps for some countries and show only those countries. I already created reliefs from SRTM-data and imported lake and river data from Natural Earth. Now I want to delete all raster and shape information that is out of the country (in my example down there, Peru). The country is another shapefile from Natural Earth.

Long story short: How do I delete all the stuff out of Peru?

[image]

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37226/how-to-crop-shapefiles-in-qgis for vector specific example. The name of the tool/operation is the same (clip) but the actual tool and location that does it differs (vector vs raster data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "delete" vector data (shape) use the clip tool in the vector menu (geoprocessing>clip). In the clip menu use the mask (i.e. borders of peru) as the clipping layer; for raster use the clipper in the raster menu (extraction>clipper). In the clipper menu choose the mask layer under clipping mode with your country borders shape as a mask

Note that you are not deleting data, rather you are extracting the data you want from the layers and save it to new layers.