# Removing erroneous symbology bands from export?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, printing, pdf, layouts

Every time I export my mxd to PDF (or jpeg, EMF, ai, gif, etc) or print to PDF, I am getting a band of symbology across the page (orange lines across picture).

[image: example]

I found this article on how to fix things, but the suggestions are either not feasible or not helping to resolve the problem (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002772). I can't really move the layer around in the TOC or change it to a solid fill because the map is too complex and it would cover other things up. Opening and exporting the MXD in ArcGIS Pro does remove the lines, but it also removes/changes several other cartographic elements to the map (I am using Data driven pages in the mxd with the data frame clipped to the feature of interest. Data Frame clipping is not incorporated into ArcGIS Pro 2.1). I am downloading the ArcGIS Pro update, but am not proficient at ArcGIS Pro at all yet so am hoping for another solution.

Has anyone come across this problem and how was it resolved?

Comment: can you export to Illustrator? then export to pdf. (This banding is usually down to the number of vertices in the polygon, this needs to be reduce and spaced out to avoid this issue)

Comment: Dissolving the problem layer did the trick. I was then able to export to PDF with no banding problems. Can you put that explanation into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: the is a qgis related answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314068/qgis-print-composer-incomplete-pdf-export >> where the issue is Adobe not ESRI or QGIS